# django all fields not appearing in admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have following model in django:

```
class ProjectScheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False,null=False)
    parent_scheme_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSchemeMaster, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    rule = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

And in `admin.py`

```
# Register your models here.
class ProjectSchemeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('id',)

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectScheme

admin.site.register(ProjectScheme, ProjectSchemeAdmin)
```

But `date fields: updated_on, created_on` don't show up on `admin form`.
[image]

I also tried without `ProjectSchemeAdmin` class, and also:

```
class ProjectSchemeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Also,

```
# list_display = [field.name for field in ProjectScheme._meta.fields if field.name != "id"]
list_display = ["id", "name","parent_scheme_id","rule","created_on", "created_by","updated_on","updated_by"]
```

But the same.

I need to get all the fields in admin form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `readonly_fields = ('created_on','updated_on')` to display the date field.

```
# Register your models here.
class ProjectSchemeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name","parent_scheme_id","rule","created_on", "created_by","updated_on","updated_by"]
    readonly_fields = ('created_on','updated_on') 

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectScheme

admin.site.register(ProjectScheme, ProjectSchemeAdmin)
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield):

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

The value `auto_now_add` is `True`. So no matter what date value you enter via admin UI, it will ultimately be overriden, which means there is no reason to display the field. In this case, as you need to display the field anyway, adding the `readonly_fields` does the trick.

Hope this helps!